# How to put a controller over all my application form if i am using grid rows

Tags: wpf, grid

My application divided into swveral `Rows`:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="45" />
            <RowDefinition Height="190" />
            <RowDefinition Height="240" />
            <RowDefinition Height="170" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Now i have `Controller` that i want to become `Visible` in some point and i have saw and i try to put it insode new `Grid` under the main `Grid` at the center but without any `Grid.Row` and it allwast at the top of my application and not at the center.

Comment: What about  `<Controller Grid.ZIndex=1 />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to center of the new grid that you are creating. Also for the new grid set the Grid.RowSpan = 4 (i.e total number of rows of main grid) and if you have defined columns also (for main grid) then set Grid.ColumnSpan = (total number of columns of main grid).